# Apache - Restrict sub folder files, listing or including parent folder or files

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

I am in a shared hosting and I have made some space for my friend to host his website. As i know the power of a simple php script, I want to restrict my parent folder being accessed by Sub folder files. What this actually mean is, "My friend would have access to his domain folder only". He can neither include any file outside his root directory nor list the files.

public_html/ is the root of my directory

public_html/myfriend.com/ is the root of my friendss directory

I want to learn both.

01: public_html/ can be accessed by all the files except the files in folder myfriend.com/

02: public_html/ can be accessed no file in sub directories.

This would help me a lot.

Reminder: As a shared hosting holder, I don't have access to httpd.conf

Any way With httpd.conf or Without httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is all done server-side, so why not to create you friend seperate FTP User, MySQL user, restrict access to SSH and in FTP settings make `/public_html/friendzone` the root folder of his FTP User?

Comment: I appreciate your comment but this is not my question. The restriction I am talking about is not a physical restriction but virtual. Php has some functions which helps you include files in parent directory folders. Like file_get_contents(), readdir(), scandir(), require(), include() this functions access files or list files from parent directory. A file from friendzone can use any file from public_html and i swear they can unlink() or rmdir() the files also. I want to limit the script of friends folder not my friend.